# LESS: Guarded Mixins like MediaQuery

Tags: less, mixins

I would like to use LESS Guarded Mixins in a way similar to MediaQuery concept, so declaring a condition that, if verified, contains a set of css rules and declaration.

For the moment I wrote this example code:

```
.color-theme(@color-type) when (@color-type='cold')
{
    color:gren;
}

.color-theme(@color-type) when (@color-type='hot')
{
    color:red;
}

text-container
{ 
  .color-theme('hot'); 
  width:960px;
}
```

My intention is to write a set of classes that must be used only if a particular condition is satisfied, in a way very similar to MediaQueries logic. 
This lines of code runs... but in this wa I should repeat the parameter value '*hot*' for each new css class.

I would like to have something like

```
when (@color-type='hot')
{
   body { ... }
   .myclass { ... }
   ...
}
```

How could I obtain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really possible exactly like that (as you can not pass a block into a mixin you are calling ... what you are trying to do is possible in Sass with the [@content directive](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/SASS-content-directive-is-a-wonderful-thing)). What you could do in Less instead, is define a mixin that outputs a particular block (cold or hot) depending on the `@color-type` variable passed.

#### a) Mixins with specific arguments:

1. First you can make a **general output mixin**, that does not show anything, no
   matter what the `@color-type` is (so you don't get an error if an undefined block is called):

   ```
   .show(@color-type) { }
   ```
2. Then you **define the blocks** (similarly to how you would do with media
   queries, except here you will need an extra mixin call):

   ```
   .show('cold') {
     body {
       color: blu;
     }
     .myclass {
       background: url(cold.png);
     }
   }

   .show('hot') {
     body {
       color: red;
     }
     .myclass {
       background: url(hot.png);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now you just need to **call the mixin**. And depending on what the variable you pass, the right block will be
   shown (or if no block with that variable has been defined, there
   will be no output).   For example now you can call show(), passing a
   variable that you defined somewhere earlier:

   ```
   @color-type: 'hot';

   .show(@color-type);
   ```

   or directly

   ```
   .show('hot');
   ```

   and the **CSS output** will be:

   ```
   body {
     color: red;
   }
   .myclass {
     background: url(hot.png);
   }
   ```

---

#### b) Guards:

Instead of defining the mixins with particlular arguments (e.g. `.show('hot'){ ... }`), you can use guards, like so: `.show(@color-type) when (@color-type = 'hot') { ... }`), or alternatively like so: `.show() when (@color-type = 'hot') { ... }` if you define the variable somewhere earlier and the just have to call the mixin `.show()` to return the respective block:

```
.show() when (@color-type = 'cold') {
  body {
    color: blue;
  }
  .myclass {
    background: url(cold.png);
  }
}

.show() when (@color-type = 'hot') {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
  .myclass {
    background: url(hot.png);
  }
}

// setting the variable
@color-type: 'hot';

// calling the mixin
.show();
```

---

**Maybe also of interest** - some discussion connected to this topic:
[Issue #965: **Mixins should accept LESS blocks**](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/965)

Comment: I just want to add here that **media queries** and **guards/mixins** really don't belong in the same category ... guards are switches used during the LESS compilation, so they respond to less variables; media queries only come to play in the CSS parsing so the vendor/deice can know which part to skip. The assumption of my answer is that you just wanted a tool to help you during the LESS processing, with deciding whether a LESS block should be printed to CSS or not.

Comment: Hi Martin,
I added this second solution in an external file (for example "external.less") imported via "import" directive in a main one ("main.less"). After that, I call the mixin in the main file and it runs correctly, but if I put "import" inside a mediaquery.... browser tells me that mixin is undefined. Why? it should be anyway defined... eventually it does not have effect in this particular screen width due to media query... Am I wrong?